# MySQLi Temporary Tables With PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want to ask if this approach will work. I have an enormous table called earnings that I often have to query.

I'm trying to optimize so that I only query according to the relevant campaign_id. I need to complete queries faster!

What I think may be the solution is to create a temporary table near the top of my PHP file, and then drop the temporary table at the end.

Between that I should be able to run more intensive queries on the temporary table because it has a much more limited data set.

I'm a bit scared about using this approach.

1. Is my general thinking about this approach right?
2. Have I written these queries and PHP correctly?
3. Will these tables be dropped correctly? I'm a bit concerned about temporary tables hanging around and crashing or even fatally stalling my instance.

   ```
   //Create temporary table for the campaign_id

   $query = "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS earnings_temp AS (SELECT * FROM earnings WHERE earning_paid_campaign_id = ? OR earning_free_campaign_id = ?)";
   if ($statement = $mysqli->prepare($query))
   {
       $statement->bind_param("ii", $campaign_id, $campaign_id);
       $statement->execute();
       $statement->close();
   }

   ....VARIOUS QUERIES ON earnings_temp.....

   //Drop temporary table for campaign_id
   $query = "DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS earnings_temp";
   if ($statement = $mysqli->prepare($query))
   {
       $statement->execute();
       $statement->close();
   }
   ```

Comment: Sorry about the code formatting. The site must be bugging because I can't put it in {} if anyone can edit to make it {} I appreciate...

Comment: @Gusstavv Gil thanks :)

Comment: NP ;). The formatter might get buggy on certain code. You can manually make it a code format by putting several spaces on front of each line. That's how I made it, since {} button bugged on me too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are right. Making temporary tables can help to optimize your workflow on certain cases. Mostly when handling large data sets (like the one you propose).
2. Your PHP seems correct. You create it, then you dispose it.
3. Don't worry about having tables hanging around and crashing or even fatally stalling my instance, since they are dropped automatically when the connection is cut.
   But beware, if tables get too big they end up moving from a memory type to a on-disk table, reducing its speed. Also if there is too many concurrent connections and you don't have enought memory it could stall the DB. But a proper config of the server can avoid that.

Comment: I see, so I'm basically moving/spreading the strain from CPU to memory/hd essentially then?

Comment: When you say "connection is cut" does that mean the table gets dropped automatically when my PHP file ends/dies?

Comment: Yep since handling large data sets make an intensive use of harddisk and memory, unless you are using indexes only, and Yep, the temporary table will be destroyed automatically when the script finishes executing

Comment: I should be able to reduce the strain if I don't use SELECT * though I think :)

Comment: That's right. But temporary tables work the best when you are making joins with lots of tables or unions or subqueries. While handling a data in a single table can also be optimized by properly using indexes for searching and fetching the data.

Comment: One question, I just used this approach and I got the error #1137 - Can't reopen table: 'earnings_temp'  what does that mean?

Comment: Were the tables created correctly?
You cannot refer to a TEMPORARY table more than once in the same query.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/temporary-table-problems.html

Comment: I see, I kind of solved that just now by creating two temporary tables - one for paid_ids and the other for free_ids......kind of wish they would fix that limitation but I'll survive. Thanks for your help! :)